# Why needed private accessor in constructor's parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have this code:

```
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private logger: Logger) {  }

  getHeroes() {
    this.logger.log('Getting heroes ...');
    return HEROES;
  }
}
```

Logger in constructor of typescript class that can be injected, but what the point of private accessor?

Why needed private accessor in constructor?

Comment: It's a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) which is shorthand for "declare a `private` property of type `Logger` and copy `logger` to `this.logger` in the constructor".   It doesn't *have* to be `private`.  You could mark it `public` or `readonly` if you want.

Comment: any idea why it should be declared private and not public?

Comment: I guess whoever wrote `HeroService` doesn't want people accessing its `logger` property directly, at least not in TypeScript code.  So is your question about parameter properties or about [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private) properties?

Comment: It can be declared as private or public both. In production build private parameters are not accessible in html templates. If you are using your service in html, you need to mark it as public to be accessible in html, private parameters can't be accessed outside typescript class.

Comment: you can also declare as `public` (it's a common practice if you use directly in the .html) or `protected`. The question is about the diference of public, private an protect:https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

The reason one might want to declare a logger as private, is because logger is an internal behavior of the component. Marking logger as private helps ensure that logger will not be directly accessed and modified by code outside of the class. It is usually considered a good practice to mark implementation details private, and expose only the methods that provide the interface of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class HeroService {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {  }
}
```

Is the same as

```
export class HeroService {
  private logger: Logger;

  constructor(logger: Logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }
}
```

Just shorter